# diff parameters in config file | diff-cmd = bbdiff is a path and not a command

Tags: svn

I am trying to get subversion to default to bbdiff for comparing files
but I cannot get it to work properly.

The ~/ .subversion/config doesn't seem to like this line

diff-cmd = bbdiff --resume --wait

It looks like 'diff-cmd' is a *path* and not a *command*

It half works with the following

diff-cmd = bbdiff

It opens the 2 files but I does not highlights the diffs, as bbdiff needs the --resume --wait options to do this.

any suggestion on how to do this anyone?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this using config file options. (diff3-has-program-arg does not do what you want).

Instead, use a shell alias:

```
alias svndiff="svn diff --diff-cmd 'bbdiff' --extensions '--resume --wait'"
```

Answer (score 0):

diff-has-program-arg
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07.html